# Why is the correlation matrix $C_{ij}=\langle c^{\dagger}_i c_j \rangle$ Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, correlation-functions

Suppose we are working with free fermions so that an eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$ is a tower of single particle states, i.e.:
$$
d_k \propto \sum_n e^{ikn}c_n \quad \text{so that} \quad |\psi^{N_p}\rangle=\prod_{k\in N_p}d_k|0\rangle,
$$
with $c_i$ being the original fermionic operators in free Hamiltonian $H$ (of course in general the coefficients need not be $e^{ikn}$, in general $\phi(k,n)$).

[I’ve read](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.11727) that the correlation matrix is Hermitian, that is
$$
(C)_{ij}\doteq \langle c^{\dagger}_ic_j\rangle \quad \text{then}\quad \langle c^{\dagger}_ic_j\rangle^{\dagger}=\langle c^{\dagger}_jc_i\rangle=?=\langle c^{\dagger}_ic_j\rangle=(C^{\dagger})_{ij}
,$$
where $\langle\cdot\rangle$ is taken wrt some eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$.

**I dont see why $\langle c^{\dagger}_ic_j\rangle=\langle c^{\dagger}_jc_i\rangle$**, could anyone help me out?

---

Edit: Just for future learners, as correctly pointed out by some answers,
$\langle c^{\dagger}_ic_j\rangle\neq \langle c^{\dagger}_jc_i\rangle$, the issue was that I made a silly mistake while taking the hermitian conjugate (forgot to take the complex conjugate).

Comment: Your source can help, perhaps.

Comment: You only need to write the averaging explicitly, and it will become as obvious as bra and ket :)

Comment: @Vadim, of course, it also worked your way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP seems to basically have this but is missing a complex conjugation somewhere. We want $(C^\dagger)_{ij}=C^*_{ji}$ that is:

$$(C^{\dagger})_{ij} = \langle c_j^\dagger c_i \rangle^*$$
the inner product simply returns a number and so complex conjugating is equivalent to taking the adjoint of the operator in the middle:
$$(C^\dagger)_{ij} = \langle (c_j^\dagger c_i)^\dagger \rangle = \langle c_i^\dagger c_j\rangle  = C_{ij}$$

Answer (score 1):

The following may not necessarily be true
$$
\langle c^{\dagger}_ic_j\rangle=\langle c^{\dagger}_jc_i\rangle 
$$

Actually, there is a whole branch of condensed matter models that depend on
$$
\langle c^{\dagger}_ic_j\rangle \neq \langle c^{\dagger}_jc_i\rangle 
$$
meaning
$$
\langle c^{\dagger}_ic_j\rangle \sim e^{\theta_{ij}i}
$$
and
$$
\langle c^{\dagger}_jc_i\rangle \sim e^{-\theta_{ij}i}
$$
which is the basis of the "emergent gauge field" paradigm reviewed in the book:

- *Quantum field Theory of Many-Body Systems* by Xiao-Gang Wen (see chapter 9).

Comment: The above answer does **not** say that $\langle c^{\dagger}_i c_j \rangle = \langle c^{\dagger}_j c_i \rangle$ but rather that $\langle c^{\dagger}_i c_j \rangle^*= \langle c^{\dagger}_j c_i \rangle$, no? Where is the assumption mentioned?

Comment: My answer does not say $\langle c_i^\dagger c_j\rangle = \langle c_j^\dagger c_i\rangle$ but rather that in the OP, the user was mistakenly trying to get to one of these when in fact they needed the other due to dropping a complex conjugation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Corrected my answer.